# How to add an attribute dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, dom, attributes

I want to get an element using id:

```
var a = document.getElementById("hello");
```

and then dynamically add an attribute to it called "labelText" and assign the value "{labeltext}" to it.

do i need to use concatenation?

i tried the following but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById("hello").setAttribute("labelText", "'{' + labelText + '}' ");
```

Comment: Your quotes are wrong.

Comment: can you please give more explanation

Comment: @SLaks where? can you please correct the code statement

Comment: `"string" + variable + "string"` => `"{" + labelText + "}"`

Comment: document.getElementById("Spot").setAttribute("labelText", "{" + labelText + "}"); i added this and it says "multiple markers at this line @Vohuman

Comment: What does "it" refer to? JavaScript interpreter? Are you using a library and the error is thrown by the library?

Comment: There is no object literal in your code. You seem to be asking how to perform string concatenation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators

Comment: i am using mvc if i say labelText="{StreetName} in the view it works fine. but now i want to use javascript to dynamically add this statement

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, hadn't read the question's title. The question now doesn't make a lot of sense for me.

Comment: my bad - I've changed the tile

Comment: `setAttribute` is the correct way of setting an attribute on a DOM element. You need to elaborate on "it didn't work".

Comment: @sarah If you want to set the attribute's value by using JavaScript, you don't need the `{}` part. JavaScript doesn't work like you server-side templating library. `.setAttribute("labelText", labelText);`

Comment: my labelText are defined in an external json file. i am using {labelText} to get this data and set it as the attribute value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing basically works, with the syntax errors first explicitly identified by Vohuman corrected.

```js
//Assign the Attribute:
var labelText='Some Value';
document.getElementById("hello").setAttribute('labelText', '{' + labelText + '}' );

//Define some variables for getting the results
var attributeEl = document.getElementById("attribute");
var theHTMLEl = document.getElementById("theHTML");

///Get the attribute value
var textLabelValue = document.getElementById("hello").getAttribute('labelText');

//Show the results:
attributeEl.textContent = textLabelValue;
theHTMLEl.textContent = document.getElementById("hello").outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
The labelText attribute is:
<div id="attribute"></div>
The resulting HTML is:
<div id="theHTML"></div>
```